# Django admin: removing app name from URL for single-app projects

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I am writing a simple Django app - say, called `base` - which has a few models. I am using Django's [built-in admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/) to manipulate the app's data. The admin is accessible via the default `^admin/` URL pattern.

Aside from Django's default `INSTALLED_APPS` (minus `django.contrib.sites`), `base` is the only app installed in my project. Is there any way to remove `base/` from the URL, such that I can access `base`'s models by simply using a path such as `/admin/model/` instead of `/admin/base/model/`?

I would ideally like `django.contrib.auth`'s models to still be accessible via `/admin/auth/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `base` in the URL, don't put it there. It's not there unless you have specifically asked it to be. Just create your URLs without that prefix.

**Edit** Apologies, I misread your question: I thought you were asking about your app's own views, not the sub-sections with admin.

This is tricky. One way of doing it would be to use the hooks for adding URLs to the base AdminSite [as described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites). You will probably need to copy the code from the ModelAdmin.get_urls method and hard-code the model name, since there won't be a way of doing that automatically.

Comment: I presume the admin requires the app name before the app's model in its URLconf (if it has one) - if I remove it, such that I'm just using `/model/` without the name of the app before it, I obviously get a 404. Are you saying I should alter the Django admin's URLconf? Is there any way I can override this without going into my Python installation's `site-packages`?

Answer (score 1):

Customizing or overriding your default Django admin site is quite easy. Here's the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) on this. The following is an example of overriding the default admin site.

Create an `admin.py` in your Django project directory (if it's not there yet). Subclass the AdminSite.

To remove the 'appname' from the admin URLs override the `get_urls()` function:

```
# myproject/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urlpatterns = super().get_urls()
        for model, model_admin in self._registry.items():
            urlpatterns += [
                path('%s/' % (model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
            ]
        return urlpatterns
```

Creae an `apps.py` in your project directory (if it's not there yet):

```
# myproject/admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

Register this in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```